# Background color of overflow menu when CLICKED android KitKat (4.4)

Tags: android, android-xml, android-menu

I have an issue with styling my toolbar and more precisely my overflow menu when i click on an item.

My xml style file is like this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/cardViewColor</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflowButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/background_action_item_toolbar</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/background_action_menu_overflow_textcolor</item>
</style>


 <style name="background_action_menu_overflow_textcolor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu.Overflow">

    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/background_action_menu_overflow_textcolor</item>
</style>
```

and my selector file like this (with the balise ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<item android:drawable="@color/cardViewColor" android:state_pressed="true"
android:state_focused="true"

/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
```

But when i clik on my overflow menu item, i have the text button that appear but when i clik on it, the background color is not set to the "cardViewcolor" (sort of blue color).
Thanks for your help,
Yass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the xml attribute through i can change the background color when i click on text button in the overflow menu.

Add this to the Theme:

```
<item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/background_action_menu_overflow_textcolor</item>
```

With the drawable defined like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true"        android:drawable="@color/cardViewColor"/>
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</selector >
```

And delete this line in the definition of the Theme:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/background_action_menu_overflow_textcolor</item>
```

And it works.I hope this will help.
Yass.